# как сохранить значение переменной в память девайса (Не в SharedPreferences)

Tags: android

ВОПРОС:
можно ли как-то сохранить значение переменной не в SharedPreferences,
а в память самого девайса (место, откуда не удаляется значение при удалении или переустановке приложения).

И как-то считать эти данные в нужный момент.

(или ... можно ли как-то при первой установке приложения сохранить на девайсе где-то отдельный текстовый файл, куда можно будет перезаписывать значение (например значение дейтсвующего deviceID))

Comment: Судя по прошлому вашему вопросу - ничего не получится) По крайней мере, запись файла за пределами папки, которая удаляется при удалении приложения/очистке данных оного требует активного участия юзера. Ему надо показать диалог с запросом на разрешение писать что-то в память девайса. Это ограничение введено с 9 или 10 андроида. До этого вам надо будет лишь запросить также диалогом запись вообще в память телефона. Ничего не надо запрашивать только на девайсах до 6 версии андроида.Однако такое приложение в магазин гугла, например, выложить просто нельзя.Также как и не поддерживающее первый вариант

Comment: Куда бы вы не сохранили это значение - оно может быть удалено в любой момент либо другим приложением, либо самим юзером (тем более если файл создан без его участия и он не знает для чего он нужен). Теоретически можно флагами манифеста запретить очистку данных приложения и включить авто-бэкап этих данных (SharedPreferences в их числе), но я не имею понятия как это работает в реале: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element#allowbackup

Comment: благодарю за ответы.